# Random movement of enemy

Tags: xna, c#

I am making a game in XNA, and I am trying to make an enemy move randomly.The game is a platform game, so the enemy only moves left and right.I want it to move right or left a little, then stop.I didn't know how to update and code it.

This is my file...[My file!](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxH95wJ2ahrPSmZial9ZRkdjdnM&usp=sharing)

Comment: More details? What does your code look like at the moment? Can you make it move non-randomly?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxH95wJ2ahrPSmZial9ZRkdjdnM&usp=sharing

Comment: this is my file.

Comment: please refer my link

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is too use two variables in your enemy class.

```
int time = 0;       // This represents the time since the last instruction
bool left = false;  // This represents the direction the enemy is going
```

You will then want to have a method that runs every x amount of time and has a random change of moving the enemy in a specific direction or stopping him.